# How to let column not be wider than a specific widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-row, flutter-column, flutter-datatable, flutter-datacell

I have following scenario, initially I have a DataTable which contains some lines (user list), with some necessary columns, which one column will expand in height when there are additional matches from a search box.

No match:

[image: no match]

Following shows an entry with match:

[image: with match]

And it shows that search matched on one of my email-addresses. As you can see the length now surpasses the table row length, and the SMS icons falls out of the table line (it is still there, but it surpasses).

The "name column" here is defined in DataCell with child as Column which is now defined like this:

```
DataCell(
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          Expanded(child: Text("${fullName}", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: matchNm==true?Colors.blue:null),)),
        ],),
        (showMatching==true&&matchMob==true)?Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Text("${contacts?[index].mobPh}",style: TextStyle(color: matchMob==true?Colors.blue:null),)),
          ],
        ):const SizedBox.shrink(),
        (showMatching==true&&matchEmail==true)?Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Text("${contacts?[index].mailAd}",style: TextStyle(color: matchEmail==true?Colors.blue:null),)),
          ],
        ):const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ],
    )),
```

How can I set the Text (i.e. with overflow with ellipsis) to not expand more than the size which is available from the length of the remaining in DataRow?

I want it to look similar like this:

[image]

Here the SMS icon remains. I have drawn an ellipsis by hand just to show how we want it to be.

Is there a way to determine the remaining space within a container or some similar (third-party) widget?

Comment: Thanx for editing my Q! (I am not too steady in english).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and used [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), Chnage Icons and Text on your need

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text('2444 501'),
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Grønmo, Roar',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'admin123456@email.com',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.email),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Icon(Icons.mobile_friendly),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Icon(Icons.message),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Sorry @Ravindra, it did not fit my use case entirely, because I need the columns in DataTable for future sort cases, so cannot use Row like you have done. I tried to use ListTile as you did instead of Text, and the subtitle for the line beneath, but it wouldn't center vertically in the DataRow. And it didn't limit the length of the email field either, so I practically got the same result.

Comment: BTW: If there is a way for the 2nd and 3rd row to receive the widths from the 1st row, then it could be solved, but how is that achieved ?